# Working with multiple client/server UDP sockets in epoll/poll/select manner

Tags: go, udp, epoll

So I want to do some experiments with c500K ("problem of having 500K concurrent connections") in Golang, and `net.ListenUDP` (and its equivalent client connection part) started in 500K goroutines in a single process is not looking like a way to achieve it.

What is the "common" pattern on writing multiple socket listeners/clients in Golang using poll/select-like model?

Comment: The "common" pattern is to have a goroutine for each network connection. However, listening on a UDP port is connectionless, so what are you trying to do?

Comment: @JimB ok, 1 goroutine per 1 listening port, that's still a lot of goroutines (65k * n interfaces)

Comment: You need some sort of state for each connection, and that's your goroutine. I still don't understand what you mean by "500K concurrent connections" on a udp port, since udp doesn't have connections. If you want to use multiple ports, that's fine, but it doesn't need to be a 1:1 mapping.